# HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration) database created but not table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-boot-maven-plugin

my old projects are working fine after I created new projects not even one works now

`.   ____          _            __ _ _ /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ 
\/  ***)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|*__/=/*/*/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.2)[0;39m

[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.465+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m

[2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting CommerceApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 16920 (C:\Users\coola\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.21.0.RELEASE\commerce\target\classes started by coola in C:\Users\coola\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.21.0.RELEASE\commerce)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.469+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.544+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.544+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.263+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.292+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.860+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)

this is my log file

[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.195+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.237+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.581+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.621+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.991+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@147f7b37
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.994+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.073+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.488+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.494+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.551+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

I think the problem is coming from here
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.874+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.874+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1410 ms
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.130+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.195+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.237+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.581+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.621+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.991+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@147f7b37
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.994+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.073+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.488+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.494+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.551+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.998+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:41.011+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started CommerceApplication in 3.985 seconds (process running for 4.934)`

this is my application.properties

`#data config
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

#jpa hibernate config

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true`

with this the database is created but inside database the table is not created.
also when I run spring boot I see no sql queries being run in console.

this doesn't happen in old projects.

I'm using STS

I tried using spring initializr still same problem.
I tried using intellij.
I tried adding other dependencies also but didn't get solved.